# Reduce space between header and headrule in standard fancyhdr, no dotfill required

Tags: spacing, fancyhdr

I want to reduce the space between the headrule and the header itself in the standard `fancyhdr` package. All topics with similar title did not gave the solution for me. 
Please help me with this simple question.

Comment: You can easily adjust this gap using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you be a bit more specific with space you mean exactly? A minimal working example would be excellent. Why did other solutions not help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a redefinition of `\headrule` to add a convenient (negative) skip before the rule is typeset; the following example code shows the necessary redefinition using `-2pt` (change this value according to your needs in the line marked `% change here`)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{
  \if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
  \vskip-2pt% change here
  \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth   
  \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark? Be careful, and remember inspector Clouzot!